# Azure Web App Private Connection to database not working

Tags: php, azure-web-app-service, azure-mysql-database

I have using a public connection to a Azure MySQL database from a Azure Web App using a PHP 7.4 stack (soon to be PHP 8.2).  Things work fine up to about 2500 requests/min and I start getting database connection timeouts.

This article indicates that the problem is likely that I am exhausting outbound connections from the Web APP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-intermittent-outbound-connection-errors

One of the suggested solutions I found elsewhere was to setup a private connection to the database, which I did.  Using VNet integration into the Web App and a private endpoint for my database.  I simply set the endpoint to an address of 10.1.1.4 to avoid having to setup a private DNS server.

So then I changed the connection URL to the database like so...

```
mysql://user:password@10.1.1.4:3306/mydatabase?serverVersion=8.0.31
```

So it does connect, but now my outbound connections seem to limited to 1.  Every overlapping query to the database times out.  What is going on here?  I went to a VNet and a private connection to get a big pipe and now it seems I have a tiny pipe.

Comment: Why not using private DNS zone ? You don't need to setup your own private DNS server.

Comment: True.  However that is simply needless complexity in this case.  The DNS record in the private DNS would simply resolve to 10.1.1.4 and the problems would remain the same.